# Make hyperlink text/description automated for certain sites

Tags: feature-request, hyperlinks, images

Certain sites are linked often in posts. Specifically, Wikipedia and other StackExchange questions.

Around 90% of the time I enter a Wikipedia link, the title of the article is what I change my text too.

For instance, http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Foo could automatically change to:

[Foo](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Foo), [Foo (Wikipedia page)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Foo) or even [Wikipedia: Foo](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Foo)

as opposed to:

[enter link description here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Foo)

Edit: Stack Overflow posts are now changing? Has it always been this way and I just didn't notice?

Comment: Really? About 100% of the time I enter a Wikipedia link, the title isn't what I change the text to. It's usually something like "You can check [this wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Foo) for more information". "You can check [Foo](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Foo)" seems less useful

Comment: @MichaelMrozek Even if you do it %1 it's still more helpful than text that is always useless.

Comment: Yeah, but if it's 1% there are probably better candidates. What if 2% of the time people just say "this wikipedia page" -- should we make that the default?

Comment: @MichaelMrozek What about "Foo (Wikipedia page)"? It makes a reasonable amount of sense in both contexts.

Comment: Links to SE questions on the same site or on the per-site meta/parent have had their title converted for a while now, but it's not cross-site. This site (MSO) converts all SE links. Note that it doesn't replace the Markdown text; it only replaces on display.

Answer (score -3):

I think the best option would be to cite the original source, and have the title automatically extracted.  This behaviour should be enabled automatically for inter-network sites (such as StackOverflow), Wikipedia, and Google search results; more sites could be added as need be.

I think the best format would be:

> [Make hyperlink text/description automated for certain sites (Meta StackOverflow)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/111980/make-hyperlink-text-description-automated-for-certain-sites)
>
> [cbroughton's Profile (StackExchange)](https://stackexchange.com/users/388647/cbroughton)

You could always change the text manually, as you can now.  But this would be better than the default text of "link".

Google search result example:

> [PHP Manual (Google)](http://www.google.co.uk/#q=PHP+Manual)

Comment: "for google search results"? What do you mean by that?

Comment: Updated with example

Comment: Gah. Posting links to google searches is pretty much never appropriate. -1 for suggesting that they should be made "pretty" automatically, i.e. encouraged.

Comment: I've seen it quite a lot if people ask a stupid question like "Where do I find...".  Right now people are posting "LMGTFY" links and hiding them... which is much worse.

Comment: Don't answer those questions (vote to close/flag/downvote), and edit any instance you find of shortened links, lmgtfy or otherwise. That content must not stay, it is of no value.

Comment: I'm not the one's answering them.  If the search was context or post sensitive (ie: fulltext) you would be able to have a look yourself at how many "LMGTFY" and short-links have actually been UP-VOTED by the community.  -- But that's not the conversation at hand.